# How many extra water heaters do we need for 5 full baths and 2 sets of washer and dryers?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, natural-gas

We purchased a home to convert it as an Airbnb for 10+ guests in Atlanta. The house currently has 3 full baths and a washer and dryer set. It also has a full basement that we are going to finish with 2 additional full baths and another set of washer and dryer. The issue is, there's only one 50-gallon gas tank water heater there.

How many additional water heaters do we need? Would you suggest adding another tank water heater or add a gas tankless one? Or would you recommend replacing the current with gas tankless?

Comment: Not so much number as type. You're looking at "commercial" water heating, and "commercial" water heaters that keep up exist. The price may make you blanch, but them's the breaks. You want to heat water for "10+ guests," it's going to cost you...

Comment: Are you locked into gas for hot water heating, or do you have a choice of fuels here?

Comment: Examine the water use by that number of people over 24 hours - then size from there… consider age and gender - some use more water…

Comment: If the property is seasonal, or only expected to be rented mostly on weekends then that will make a difference on your choice between tank and tankless.  No need to keep a tank of water warm if the next guests wont arrive for 4-5 days.

Answer (score 2):

You will not get nearly the flow rate needed at temp from an on-demand tankless WH in your situation. I'd suggest replacing the existing WH with at least an 80 gallon WH if not 120 gal. That way you have a lot of stored hot water, ready to be used by your guests.   I know tank type WH's aren't currently in vogue, but they are practical.

Comment: You can defiantly get on-demand gas water heaters that can handle this load, you just need to look a small commercial units and not typical residential ones. A lot of hotel chains now require that builders use tankless on-demand water heaters in their specifications.

Comment: @pdd Probably so, but overkill, IMHO for a residence and very expensive. Also, on=-demand WH aren't well suited to HW recirc.   With the amount of insulation now on tank type WHs, I don't think the extra complexity of tankless is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

In your application you will be dealing with a high peak demand. There's a higher chance that the showers will be used at the same time or within a narrow window of each other. So you will want to have either a larger hot water storage capacity or have a on-demand gas water heater that can handle the peak flow.

This can be achieved many different ways but the best option will depend on factors such as, room for new equipment, arrangement of existing plumbing, arrangement of new pluming, available budget, venting restrictions, available gas pressure and capacity...

Some options are:

- Add a second water heater
- Replacing the existing with one larger water heater
- Add a storage tank and circulation pump between the existing water heater or a new water heater
- Add a on-demand gas water heater (there are defiantly units that can provide the required peak flow for this application)
- Combinations of the above

If you want to get an idea of capacities that you would need, most water heater manufactures provide online tools to help determine what you would need. [Here is an example of one provided by AO Smith](https://www.hotwater.com/product-selector/).

[Here are the recommendations that I received when I completed the tool with your parameters.](https://www.hotwater.com/product-selector/#results?1=Long&2=5%20Showers&3=4%20Showers&4=Large&5=No&6=Natural%20Gas&7=Plenty&zipcode=30301&Venting%20Preference=I%27m%20Not%20Sure)

I looked up that on-demand water heater and found on line pricing around $3200.00.

In your case, you would really benefit from determining a rough budget and talking to some local professionals who can advise on what best fits your budget and application.